# Post Ajax and get empty object in Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

When I get the post data in `nodejs` from Ajax call, it can be displayed in `console.log`, but when I want to assign it to another variable, or just display on page it  turns to `[object, object]`.
Why so?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5075/testEditmode.html',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: info2value + '|' + colorvalue + '|' 
});
```

---

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post('/testEditmode.html', function (req, res) {
//            console.log(req.body);


requestData = '';
requestData += req.body;
console.log(requestData.toString());
//            console.log(req.body);
var splited = requestData.split("|");
var splitedCoords = requestData.split(",");
```

`Request data = [object, object]` but `console.log(req.body)` displays what it should. `toString()` didn't help.

What shall I do ?

Comment: `req.body` is an object, what do you expect `+= req.body` to result in?

Comment: `info2value + '|' + colorvalue + '|'` doesn't look anything like the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format!

Comment: `[object, object]` is what happens when you turn an object into a string. You can't just do a 'var dump' like in php. You could write your own method to do so, though

Comment: I just want to catch data as I could do here, without express:

[code]
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
if (req.method === "POST") {
        req.on('data', function (data) {
           
            requestData = '';
            requestData += data;
[/code]

Comment: @Quentin: +1. Although gladly [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) does not have a `'Content-Type'` option :-)

Comment: Ah, it's `contentType` … although I wouldn't put it past them to alias `Content-Type` to it quietly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace `data` in your jQuery request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  json: true, // added this
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5075/testEditmode.html',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  data: {infoValue: info2value + '|' + colorvalue + '|'}
});
```

You can then do:

```
requestData = '';
requestData += req.body.infoValue;
```

If you use the `body-parser` middleware you are telling express to parse the body of the request and now `req.body` is an object, so you're actually doing:

```
var requestData = '' + {}; // "[object Object]" - Same as obj.toString()
```

and not really mutating `req.body`, that's why `req.body` is still an object.